# Date Range in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, plsql

If I have table with a Date column (Date field) called `created_date`, with values like "9/2/2010 5:25:42 PM".

I want to select all rows from a `start_date` to a `end_date`. However, the `end_date` may be `null`. In this case, I want to select all rows where `created_date` is greater than `end_date`.

Comment: I think you meant to say "...where created_date is greater than start_date".  You can't meaningfully compare created_date to end_date if end_date is NULL.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since toDate (which can be null) is a host variable, it's easier than the solutions already given (which are all wrong in that regard, btw)

```
select * from mytable
  where created_date between v_fromdate
                         and nvl(v_todate, to_date('31.12.9999','dd.mm.yyyy'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why just use a simple SQL query for that, like this one:

```
select xxx from table_names where created_date is null or (created_date >= to_date("02/09/2010", "dd/mm/yyyy") and created_date <= to_date("03/09/2010", "dd/mm/yyyy"));
```

**Edit**

You can define a query like the one defined by *ammoQ*, i.e. something like that:

```
select xxx from table_names where created_date is null or created_date >= start_date and created_date <= nvl(end_date, to_date("31/12/9999", "dd/mm/yyyy"));
```

However, as you are using PL/SQL, you can check the nullability of `end_date` parameter:

```
IF end_date IS NULL THEN
    select xxx from table_names where created_date is null or created_date >= start_date;
ELSIF
    select xxx from table_names where created_date is null or created_date >= start_date and created_date <= end_date;
END IF;
```

Note that you can remove the `created_date is null` condition if `created_date` is not a nullable column...

Comment: But I have already mentioned that to date in this case 3rd Sept,2010 may be null.In this case I have to fetch all the data >= from date

Comment: ahh just few sec faster then me :)

Comment: @Suvonkar Ok, I didn't get your condition correclty. I edited your question as well as my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If i took it right from your question
this should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE created_date >= to_date('01.09.2010', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
  AND (end_date  <= to_date('02.09.2010', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
  OR end_date   IS NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

select *
from TABLE
where created_date >= '2010-09-02' 
and (created_date is NULL or created_date <= '2010-09-03')

Comment: I don't like this way to do it much, since it will result in a full table scan, even if there is an index on created_date.

Comment: BTW, assuming created_date is a date column, your solution only works if yyyy-mm-dd is the default date format.

Comment: The last comment is not true, the solution will work with full date time format 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss' or 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss'. The comparison is implicit. And yes, I tested it.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from yourtable
where created_date >= @StartDate AND created_date <=ISNULL(@EndDate,created_date)
```

Comment: `NVL`, not `ISNULL` - this is Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
  FROM A_TABLE
  WHERE CREATED_DATE >= &START_DATE AND
        (CREATED_DATE <= &END_DATE OR
         &END_DATE IS NULL)
```